# How to get the taxonomy translated in URLs?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a bilingual site with localized taxonomy terms used as categories.

I would like to achieve this:

`http://www.mysite.com/about/pageinenglish`

`http://www.mysite.com/apropos/pageinfrench`

(A propos means about in French)

But I only have:

`http://www.mysite.com/about/pageinfrench`

How can I translate the taxonomy in urls?

**EDIT**

I have pathauto configured with i18n terms (which are only available in TAXONOMY TERM PATHS)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this post on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/290421).
I am in the same position as you, but it seems that there aren't any solutions for D7.

---

**Edit**

I'm editing this so it can be visible that this is already possible.
As of writing this there wasn't any way of achieving this. As of drupal 8 comming soon there were new modules developed to help translation processes. They are in the core of drupal 8 and available as modules for drupal 7. So the right answer is what @Pere answered in the bellow answer.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  If you wish to add a question as a favorite, you can click the star icon to the left of the original question at the top of each page.

Comment: Indeed. Do you think it would work though with translated rather than localised taxonomy?

Answer (score 5):

I've been able to do that, using [Entity Translation](https://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) instead of Taxonomy translation (part of [i18n](https://drupal.org/project/i18n)) for translating taxonomy terms, and using the [Title](https://drupal.org/project/title) module to replace the **name field** of the taxonomy term and making it translatable.

It works so far.

Comment: But this way when we edit a node it shows origin term not translated terms while adding new nodes ie: in term reference fileds, please suggest ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this, which supports token. You just need to modify the pathauto rule with the provided token.

https://drupal.org/project/pathauto_i18n_taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) suite of modules, do you have i18n taxonomy enabled?

You can also use the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to translate your URLs using tokens.

Comment: Yes, i18n taxonomy is enabled and terms are localized (not translated). I also have pathauto set up with i18n terms but alias are not produced in French when bulk updating. (see screen shot in my edit)

Comment: See @ucaka answer, this is currently an issue with localized terms using *i18n* and *pathauto*

Answer (score 0):

Some tokens are not provided by the token list, but do work. Tokens that have `:1:` in them for instance. Replace the `:1:` with `:0:`, and there you go…

[(Source)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158010/taxonomy-i18n-does-not-translate-term-name-in-a-term-page/217651#217651)