# Taxonomy i18n does not translate term name in a term page

Tags: i18n-l10n

I set option Localized in my Vocabulary "Categories" and translated all the terms in english French and german some of them. The default language is russian.
Term page title has russian name: http://tlito.ru/en/categories/debugging in all the languages. I've made html-document title in need language using Page Title module. But the page title rest russian.
Please what is this bug?

Answer (score 2):

Some tokens are not provided in the token list, but do the job, for instance:

```
[node:field-myvocabulary:0:i18n-name]/[node:title]
```

`[node:field-myvocabulary:1:i18n-name]/[node:title]` (with the `:1`) is provided by the token list (but doesn't work), `[node:field-myvocabulary:0:i18n-name]/[node:title]` (with the `:0`) is not provided, but doés work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: [Vocabulary Name value doesn't get translated](https://www.drupal.org/node/29697). It dates from 2005 (!), related to D6, status "won't fix". However comment # 2 in that issue states:

> I have used the locale module to translate the name of the vocabulary, and display it with t($vocabulary->name). If all modules would display the name this way (e.g. taxonomy_menu does it), then there is no need for a new database table i18n_vocabulary.

The **t($vocabulary->name)** seems like a possible/partial work around to consider, i.e. from within a (custom) module.

There is a more recent similar issue, i.e. [Vocabulary names are not translated](https://www.drupal.org/node/2259923). That one is for D7, with status "needs work".

Another potential work around could be to have a separate taxonomy for each language (and with a "name" corresponding to that language). Of course, you'd have to think how to best use these separated taxonomies for each content type (a kind of "solution to the problem, changes the problem) ...

That's probably the best you can get these days. Does this somehow "answer the question"?

Comment: this does not answer my question, cause https://www.drupal.org/node/2259923#comment-10012705 the patch does not work for me. But separate taxonomy is uncomfortable. Other my sites does not need such actions, and everything work well. The problem rests on http://tlito.ru/en/categories/site-development.

Comment: sorry that you need to answer without right solution. but there was one more field Name. and i do not know when it appears. so after i delete this becomes good. visit tlito.ru now to check